# It may take a long time to start a data flow job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I start a data flow job, it sometimes waits for more than 30 minutes without being allocated an instance.

What is happen??

Comment: Prefer E2 or N1 family's type then N2. More resources available and less time to wait to provision the cluster before starting the processing

Comment: Certainly 30 mins is a lot for the VM, they should take around 5 mins in Java and 7 in Python (based on my experience). I would suggest to check the worker startup logs and see if something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dataflow Job is getting slow because the time needed to start the VMs on Google Compute Engine grows with the number of VMs you start, and in general VM startup and shutdown performance can have high variance.

you can look at Cloud Logs for your job ID, and see if there's any logging going on, also you can check the Dataflow monitoring interface inside your Dataflow job.[1]

you can enable autoscaling[2] instead of specifying a large number of instances manually, it should gradually scale to the appropriate number of VMs at the appropriate moment in the job's lifetime.

Without autoscaling, you have to choose a fixed number of workers by specifying workers to execute your pipeline. As the input workload varies over time, this number can become either too high or too low. Provisioning too many workers results in unnecessary extra cost, and provisioning too few workers results in higher latency for processed data. By enabling autoscaling, resources are used only as they are needed.

The objective of autoscaling  is to minimize backlog while maximizing worker utilization and throughput, and quickly react to spikes in load.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-autoscaling

Comment: I think this usecase has too many steps more than 150 steps...

Comment: There is cause of  without being allocated an instance.

Comment: now,  a  was pending more than 24hours...      it status is "starting" but not progress.

Comment: "dataflow job cancel "  command is not unavailable..  because this job is not starting....